# How to read from /dev/random in Swift

Tags: random, swift

I'm having trouble finding an example of how to open a file in Swift, specifically reading from /dev/random for truly random numbers into an array.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about reading files, you need to use `NSFileManager`. Swift doesn't have its own file API. Also, you can't simply open the file; you need to use a file handler since `/dev/random` will keep outputting forever.

Here's an example:

```
let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let randomPath = "/dev/random"

if manager.fileExistsAtPath(randomPath) {
    let handle = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: randomPath)

    if let validHandle = handle {
        let desiredLength = 256

        // Warning: Instead of returning NSData?, this method throws an exception if there's an error. Consider adding additional error handling.
        let fileData = validHandle.readDataOfLength(desiredLength)
        let fileString = NSString(data: fileData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        if (fileString != nil) {
            println(fileString!)
        }
    }   
}
```

Example console output:

> ¬Ñ@<4r-ÐÛÍäÓ-(*Âý3o÷-»e2
>   @äÂx<øWýsñniâõãQüÕ£ÆsûÄÏþDÊU²OÑ9H)úûÓWhAóûoÎºfßpÍC%M¤ò«ÿ@'-gVüü]®%åYÒ{»j>ä©æ¨Zì¿¿Bþxû,«1´£¾E¸Ju|`ëérßNeÃ²WÙé-î#ê05¿
>   JF-Ëë«î=¤<5ë/p¨¾üæü5è«î%ãå.öÅª¿¯¨ôø+EeÅþUå5ì%ÿ¼pÕÊ:oÐ

That said, if your intent is loading random numbers in an array, you should just use `arc4random_uniform()`, which will return a uniformly distributed random number:

```
var randomNumbers = [Int]()

for i in 1...10 {
    randomNumbers.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(1000)))
}

println(randomNumbers)
```

Example output:

> [27, 796, 150, 439, 955, 678, 556, 816, 571, 130]

Comment: Thanks! I got it working in a Playground, and I got what you got.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness: You can use open/read/write/close in Swift pretty much the same way as you would in C:

```
var array = [UInt8](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)

let fd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY)
if fd != -1 {
    read(fd, &array, UInt(sizeofValue(array) * array.count))
    close(fd)
    println(array)
}
```